# export the Console answer to xml

Tags: javascript, xml, export

Hi I have a script giving a response in the console,
What I want is to create a form in html parse the submit and export to an XML file

I use "npm xmlbuilder"

How can I save it to a file (ex: test.xml)?

This is the example script:

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');    
var xml = builder.create('root')
      .ele('xmlbuilder')
        .ele('repo', {'type': 'git'}, 'git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git')
      .end({ pretty: true});

    console.log(xml);
```

And the result I want to put in test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <xmlbuilder>
    <repo type="git">git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git</repo>
  </xmlbuilder>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your answer correctly, you already have a finished xml and you just want it into a file? 
did you try something like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-write-data-in-a-text-file/) for writing into a file ?